# How to expand a div beyond the parent list container without JavaScript

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to make an 'About Us' page for a client website and essentially would like to accomplish a popup modal that fills the viewport of the browser with a 2rem gap around it. This modal would contain the employee picture, name, bio and education. I am looking for a pure CSS solution to this problem. The employee images that you click on to make the modal appear are list items of an unordered list that are populated by php. The problem I am having is getting the modal to extend beyond the `<ul>`. Below is a wireframe of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Wireframe before click]
<sub>(source: [faithalaska.com](https://faithalaska.com/assets/img/Wireframe-before-click.png))</sub>

[image: Wireframe after click]
<sub>(source: [faithalaska.com](https://faithalaska.com/assets/img/Wireframe-after-click.png))</sub>

I've tried some solutions from similar questions (listed below) but they didn't resolve my problem.
[Extend child div beyond container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849717/extend-child-div-beyond-container-div)
[Expand DIV beyond parent List Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249500/expand-div-beyond-parent-list-item)

This is the markup that I'm using:

```css
div {
  &.container {
    >div {
      &.container {
        &.whoWeAre {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
          >ul {
            &.whoWeAre {
              width: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
              position: relative;
              clear: both;
              list-style-type: none;
              display: inline-block;
              @media only screen and (min-width: 75em) {
                padding: 0;
              }
              >input {
                &.dossierToggle {
                  position: absolute;
                  left: -4000px;
                  top: -4000px;
                  &:checked {
                    ~li {
                      position: absolute;
                      width: 100vw;
                      height: 100vh;
                      margin: 2rem;
                      >div {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              >li {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                position: relative;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border: none;
                line-height: 2.2rem;
                text-align: left;
                float: left;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
                animation: slide-in-blurred-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000) both;
                @media only screen and (min-width: 75em) {
                  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
                  height: 33rem;
                  margin-bottom: 2rem;
                  margin-right: 1rem;
                  margin-left: 1rem;
                  border: 1px solid $faint-grey;
                  background: orange;
                }
                >label {
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  display: block;
                  position: relative;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>who we are</h2>
  <h6>meet our pastors</h6>
  <div class="container whoWeAre">
    <ul class="whoWeAre">
      <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE flc='1' and pastor='1' ORDER BY `positionRank`";
    $query = $connection->query( $sql );
    if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {
     while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="dossierToggle" id="toggle<?php echo $row[ " nameFirst " ] . $row[ "nameLast " ]; ?>">
        <li>
          <label for="toggle<?php echo $row[ " nameFirst " ] . $row[ "nameLast " ]; ?>"></label>
          <div></div>
        </li>
        <?php } } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not wanting to use JavaScript? How are you expecting the clickability to work without it? Are you expecting the entire page to reload each time something is clicked?

Comment: The only reason I am not wanting to use JavaScript is because of a challenge from a friend. As for clickability, I have already made a pure css slider that uses radio button inputs to change slides so I thought I would try this one with a checkbox input as it seemed most appropriate for completing the task. I will be applying a transition it so that it seems to grow from the middle of the profile pic into the large modal.